# draw opengl texture at full screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I want to draw opengl texture at full screen.

(texture : 128x128   ===> device screen : 320x480)

Below code works good, but texture is small.

I have to use only glFrustumf function(not glOrthof function).

How can I draw texture in full screen size?

```
// this is android source code
float ratio = (float) screenWidth / screenHeight;
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);

GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0.0f, 0.0f, -2.5f, // eye
 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // center
 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // up

// draw blah blah
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you have to use `glFrustum` only? Switching to `glOrtho` for drawing the background, then switching to `glFrustum` for regular drawing would be the canonical solution.

BTW: `gluLookAt` must happen in the modelview matrix, not in the projection matrix like you do right now. As it stands your code is broken and if you were a student in one of my OpenGL classes I'd give you negative points for this cardinal error.